# SAML assertion verification works in spring-security version 5.4.2, but not in 5.7.1

Tags: spring-security, saml, saml-2.0

With spring-security 5.7.1 I get

```
Invalid signature for object [id6...]
```

This is the error message of the signature verification of the saml assertion. But with version 5.4.2 it works.

This is my application.yml

```
spring:
 security:
  saml2:
   relyingparty:
    registration:
     okta-saml:
      identityprovider:
       entity-id: http://www.okta.com/e...
       verification:
        credentials:
         - certificate-location: "classpath:saml-certificate/okta.crt"
       singlesignon:
        url: https://dev-7....okta.com/app/dev-7..._appsaml_1/e.../sso/saml
        sign-request: false
```

Maybe something must be changed in application.yml?

Answer (score 0):

have seen the Same problem after updating to Spring Boot 2.7.
the problem is related to verifying the SAML response signature

2022-06-23 17:26:52.747 DEBUG 5308 --- [nio-8282-exec-8] o.o.x.s.s.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine : Failed to establish trust of KeyInfo-derived credential 2022-06-23 17:26:52.747 DEBUG 5308 --- [nio-8282-exec-8] o.o.x.s.s.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine : Failed to verify signature and/or establish trust using any KeyInfo-derived credentials 2022-06-23 17:26:52.747 DEBUG 5308 --- [nio-8282-exec-8] .x.s.s.i.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine : Attempting to verify signature using trusted credentials 2022-06-23 17:26:52.747 DEBUG 5308 --- [nio-8282-exec-8] .x.s.s.i.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine : Failed to verify signature using either KeyInfo-derived or directly trusted credentials

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).